# PHP system Cookies does not generate in Server

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

I have tested my site which has a login system written in php and it is working fine in the local server (im using xampp). I have uploaded the files into the web server.
Say I have given the credentials and then i am loging in. What its supposed to do is create sessions and redirect me to another page called home.php. This is working fine in the local server but not in the web server. It doesn't create the sessions as its supposed to.

this is the code in the login.php:

```
<?php
require 'core/init.php';
$general->logged_in_protect();

if (empty($_POST) === false) {

$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);

if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, but we need your username and password.';
} else if ($users->user_exists($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry that username doesn\'t exists.';
} else if ($users->email_confirmed($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, but you need to activate your account.
                 Please check your email.';
} else {
    if (strlen($password) > 18) {
        $errors[] = 'The password should be less than 18 characters, without spacing.';
    }
    $login = $users->login($username, $password);
    if ($login === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, that username/password is invalid';
    }else {
        session_regenerate_id(true);// destroying the old session id and creating a new one
        $_SESSION['id'] =  $login;
        header('Location: home.php');
        exit();
    }
}
}
?>
```

where could be the problem? please advice,

thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your PHP logs. Let us know if there is anything in there.

Comment: and did it redirect you to home.php? in productive server.

Comment: Are cookies allowed to be set by the productive server?

Comment: Do you explicitely call session_start() anywhere? Your development server might auto-start the sessions on each request and your production environment does not.

Comment: the problem was at the session save path, Thank you all for helping! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found where the question is, The problem was in session data or more clearly session_save_path
I am using iPage for the first time and their path was set to `"/var/php_sessions"`
I have set that back to `/temp` now the things are working as it should be